# How to set an eclipse/webapp maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

What's the correct form to set up a maven webapp project?

It should be able to:

- Run with the eclipse embedded tomcat (available in the servers tab).
  This way I can run/debug the application like a regular webapp.
- Run with the maven plugin tomcat7. So far I can only run the run-war
  goal, couldnt make the "run" goal work =/

I have followed some tutorials, but couldnt make all these things to work properly. 
When I follow the [MkYong](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-do-use-maven-to-create-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse/) suggestion, I can run with the embedded tomcat, but the project dependencies are changed to classpath variables. This is not a good consequence at all, since the project loses the ability to dynamically set the dependencies.

I use Eclipse Juno (I'd rather wait Kepler for a couple of months to check it is really stable), m2e and m2e-wtp plugins, and have 2 kinds of projects: one is based in JSF (the front-end) and another in Apache CXF (the back-end). I hope these two can be hot deployed (when a resource changes, embedded tomcat automatically publishes it) in development environment to improve productivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source taken from](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/felipegaucho/archive/2009/12/28/webapps-eclipse-and-maven-maven-war-plugin)

Web applications created by the Eclipse IDE contains an annoying folder WebContent to host the web resources and deployment descriptors. Quite natural for Eclipse users, this feature ignores the Maven convention and force the developers to hack the pom files in order to get the project up and running in Eclipse. In this aspect, Eclipse if far behind the other IDEs regarding Maven support, even if you consider the very good M2Eclipse plugin. So, for you lazy Christmas hackers, here it is a solution for the Maven integration problems in Eclipse based on the maven-war-plugin.

**ERRATA:** please use the WTP plugin instead of changing the project structure.  I figured out the wtp plugin after writting this blog, so I suggest you to check just the 1st and the 3th steps of the below instructions. I kept the original blog information in case you really need or want to change the project structure.

1. Create a Web Project in Eclipse: right-click on the Project Explorer

   > New > Project > Web \ Dynamic Web Project
2. Create a pom.xml file in the project root folder, with the following
   content:

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>org.cejug</groupId>
   <artifactId>webapp-test</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>webapp-test Maven Webapp</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
           <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
           <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>

   <build>
       <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.0.2</version>
               <configuration>
                   <webResources>
                       <resource>
                           <directory>${basedir}/WebContent</directory>
                       </resource>
                   </webResources>
                   <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                   <warSourceExcludes>WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</warSourceExcludes>
                   <archiveClasses>false</archiveClasses>
                   <archive>
                       <manifest>
                           <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                           <classpathPrefix />
                       </manifest>
                       <manifestEntries>
                           <url>${pom.url}</url>
                           <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                           <Implementation-Title>${project.name}</Implementation-Title>
                           <Implementation-Vendor>CEJUG</Implementation-Vendor>
                           <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                           <Built-By>${user.name}</Built-By>
                           <Built-OS>${os.name}</Built-OS>
                           <Build-Date>${timestamp}</Build-Date>
                           <SCM>${buildNumber}</SCM>
                       </manifestEntries>
                   </archive>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
3. Compile and prepare the project for eclipse:

   ```
   mvn -Dwtpversion=2.0 compile eclipse:eclipse
   ```

Notice the usage of the plugin -Dwtpversion to enable Maven to add Eclipse WTP Support to the project. That simple flag do the trick :). Actually just using that flag will work, but not all plugins of Eclipse will work out of the box without the WebContent folder - it is up to you to decide if it is worthy to modify your project structure or just go straight ahead with the plain Maven folder.

Done, now you can refresh the project in Eclipse and continue to work. Remember that jjust the resources folder is hard coded in Eclipse, the src/main/java continues as Maven expects. Perhaps some day we can have the confluence between the conventions of Maven and Eclipse and then we will finally becomes free of this daily basis hacks.

Answer (score 0):

We are using Kepler and we find it quite stable. You can create a normal Dynamic Web Project and then right click and make the project Maven enable. Then you have hot deploy and maven management POM.
Also you can have all Maven goals there.